# beanshell sampler, i want access java code from jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I have stuck with below error in `jmeter`.

Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of'

bean shell code:

```
import tools.JmeterTools; 

JmeterTools jt = new JmeterTools();  

int num = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("A1"));

num = jt.randInt(num);  

vars.put("A1", num.toString());  

num =  Integer.parseInt(vars.get("B1")); 

num = jt.sqrInt(num);   

vars.put("B1", num.toString());  

vars.put("B2", jt.sqrstr(vars.get("B2")));  

}
```

eclipse code:

```
package tools;
import java.util.Random;

public class JmeterTools {

    public JmeterTools(){
    }

    public int randInt (int x){
        Random randomGenerator= new Random();
        return randomGenerator.nextInt(x);
    }

    public int sqrInt(int x){
        return x*x;
    }

    public String sqrstr(String x){
        int y= Integer.parseInt(x);
        return String.valueOf(y*y);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there really a closing paranthesis at the end of your BeanShell code?

Comment: no, that paranthesis is for try and catch block

Answer (score 1):

Did you:

- export your JmeterTools class as a JAR
- Is the JAR OK ?
- put the JAR in jmeter/lib folder ?

Also, you have a **}** at end of your beanshell code that shouldn't be there.

Comment: yes, i have imported jar from eclipse and kept in lib/ext folder in jmeter

Comment: It must be in lib not lib/ext ,can you show the folder structure of your jar once you expand it ?

Comment: Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``    import tools.JmeterTools;           JmeterTools jt = new JmeterTools();      . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: JmeterTools not found in namespace

Comment: folder structure: D:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\JmeterHelper.jar

Comment: Move the jar to "lib" (instead of "lib/ext"), as UBIK said.

Comment: i have moved jar to lib folder, still error is coming :(

Comment: can you show full error, and show what the JAR contains expanded in terms of folder hierarchy ?

Comment: i mentioned full error in 3rd comment. i didn't understand " show what the JAR contains expanded in terms of folder hierarchy". could you plz explain  a little bit clear.